# prerequisites for angular js and node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I will have to start working with angular js and node js pretty soon. I do not know much about javascript, what would be a good way to start. Can I just pick a book an each or do i need to learn something about javascript before getting into these technologies.

Comment: [This](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) is an incredible resource to get you started, but you need to have good javascript knowledge first, so you can develop easily with Node.js + AngularJS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because there are many possible answers and the answers you seek already exist on SO. You do not need a book to learn angular/node. There are plenty of tutorials that exist for free as well as great videos on youtube that go to great lengths to explain how it works. Yes you do need a general understanding of javascript, but you do not need to be an expert. In fact, it's generally easier to learn Angular if you don't have much of a strong JS background. Nodejs is another story. For node you'll need a decent/strong understanding of js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the most important question would be what languages you do know / use, because if you know nothing (*Jon Snow*) you should perhaps look for some after hours schooling. If you are proficient in other languages, learning a syntax is quite easy **compared** to learning how to program.

For a decent start at javascript, I found [Javascript: The Definitive Guide from O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) a very good book to own, and now after 3 years of fulltime working in javascript i still open it from time to time.

For Node.js, I learnt most things at [nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io/). But I should have to add that I don't work with node.js, nor have I done anything worth mentioning in it. I would imagine that [O'Reilly](http://search.oreilly.com/?i=1;q=Node;q1=Books;x=0;x1=t1;y=0&act=fc_contenttype_Books) offers some good books on the subject.

For Angular I would first of recommend the free course on [codeschool](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/) as a starting point. I own [AngularJS: Up and Running from O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033486.do), and can wholeheartedly recommend it, as it reads easy and is still to the point.
A friend of mine swears by the [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/). This is a **very** complete book, but I don't like the markup, which has put me off of the book more than it should have :)

Furthermore, angular hosts a good [developers guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) and [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).
And per usual, for urgent questions open up an IRC application, or for somewhat less urgent matter post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, was hoping to get some answer like your. I know Java very well and have been programming for 10 years. Not so much in Javascript.

Comment: In that case, look into [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), javascript is very loosely based, typescript tries to fix that. I don't use it myself, because the implementation to get it to run with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) isn't as straightforward as I'd like it to be. We use browserify to compile our code into a single file where you can easily require other files.   
I prefer browserify over typescript as typescript only renders your strict code back to loose javascript.